# DOS/Command Prompt Power Mode

Tags: windows, command-line, bootable-media

from where can i get a Bootable or Executable Power Mode DOS/Command Prompt.

Comment: what, exactly, are you looking for? The comments you left on the two extant answers don't really explain the question to me :)

Comment: Maybe you could also explain the specific problem you are trying to solve.  That may allow us to better understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for "Administrator Mode" (or Elevated Mode) and not "Power Mode"
So, right-click the Command Prompt shortcut, and then click Run as administrator.
(Or: Win+R > Type: cmd > Ctrl+Shift+Enter)
And any bootable DOS disk will have the administrator rights.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but kinda solves my problem.. the bootable disk will have elevated rights for the current windows installation.. i want it to be any instalation

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you're asking, but you cannot *boot cmd*.

Normal DOS (as opposed to abnormal :) is bootable because it is an operating system. When working under Windows you're merely using a feature that emulates DOS. But you cannot boot into it, and avoid Windows altogether.

Also, I don't recall anything called "DOS power mode".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but... are you asking for [this](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx)?

Comment: no no thats not it

Comment: its normal DOS which is bootable and overrides windows securities on files, thats why its called "Power Mode", the one we have in windows is "User Mode"

Answer (score 0):

[Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) is probably what you want.

Comment: no no thats not it

Comment: its normal DOS which is bootable and overrides windows securities on files, thats why its called "Power Mode", the one we have in windows is "User Mode"